# by item random effects in a mixed effects model, when the same item appears in different conditions

Tags: mixed-model, experiment-design

I am analysing some experimental data using mixed effects modelling. I would normally include a by-item random slope, however I am wondering if it makes any sense given my experimental design:

There are two experimental conditions (A & B), and it's a within-participant design. However, I'm not using A and B as predictors for the DV. I record participants' responses as well (say, "correct" and "incorrect"), and then sort my DV by three conditions: (1)A+correct, (2)B+correct, (3)B+incorrect. This means that I might essentially have the same item in different conditions. Am I right in thinking that any by-item variance (at least in B+correct / B+incorrect conditions) will then not be random, but is due to the experimental manipulation? Would it perhaps make sense to not include items as my random effect at all?

To sum up, right now my model is

> `DV ~ condition + (condition | subject) + (condition | item)`

but I wonder if, given my design, it should just be

> `DV ~ condition + (condition | subject)`